# Problem running 'rails s' after adding gem docx_converter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, publisher

TL;DR:

I should have used the docx gem and not the (older) docx_converter. This seems much more compatible with Rails 5.2.

---

I'm learning rails and have a working application. However, when I add the gem docx_converter to my Gemfile (so I can convert Word files to markdown to work on further), the server fails to launch.

The application has three models: Company, which has_many Users, which has_many Projects. (Users is controlled by Devise, and Company has_many Projects through Users.) When a user creates a project, they can upload a file to that project using active_storage, and it's stored on disk in my dev environment (which is what I'm concerned with here).

I have no problem with any of the above - I can create users and projects, and add and remove files from the projects.

However, if I add `gem 'docx_converter'` to my Gemfile and run `bundle update`, I can no longer run the rails server. Immediately before this action, all is fine. Immediately after, the server won't run and the traceback (last few lines) is:

```bash
    10: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     9: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/docx_converter-1.0.0/lib/docx_converter.rb:18:in `<main>'
     8: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     7: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     6: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     5: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
     4: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
     1: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- publishr (LoadError)
```

Given the references to bootsnap, I tried removing this from the Gemfile and config/boot.rb, but that led to the same error in a different place but about the same thing (publishr):

```bash
    10: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     9: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     8: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     7: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     6: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     5: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
     4: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/docx_converter-1.0.0/lib/docx_converter.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     2: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': cannot load such file -- publishr (LoadError)
```

I've tried installing publishr via "gem install publishr" but it doesn't help.

My Gemfile is:

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Manually added gems
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.6'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.6.2'
gem 'cancancan', '~>3.0.1'
gem 'docx_converter', '~>1.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.7.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

There seems to be an issue with this gem and Rails 5.2.3 but does anyone know what's going on here and how I could get it working? (Or alternatively, a different gem for converting a Word docx file to something usable)

Comment: could you add the `gem install publishr` and do bundle install instead of bundle update?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @neo. I'd already tried `gem install publishr` but that wasn't enough. Check my answer below - I had to require both publishr and a specific version of rubyzip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a certain amount of diving down rabbit holes, I found that I needed to explicitly require two extra gems for docx_converter to work, and also had to lock the version of one of them.

```
gem 'publishr'
gem 'rubyzip', '~>0.9.9'
gem 'docx_converter', '~>1.0.0'
```

I've not exhaustively tested the functionality, but at least the server now starts! Thanks for the suggestions, everyone!

#### Edit

Even after getting the server running, I had problems with this gem - as @engineersmnky said, it's pretty old and poorly documented. So I've swapped to the [docx gem](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx), which doesn't try to do as much but does seem (a) to load without problems on Rails 5.2 and (b) to work!

Comment: That is the issue given the fact that the line referenced shows you it need `publishr` but for some reason the maintainer of `docx_converter` did not add it as a dependency. All that being said do you really want to use a gem that has not had any substantial change made to it in 5 years?

Comment: Ideally not, @engineersmnky, but there don't seem to be many choices! Have you come across any other ways to access the content of Word files in a Rails app? (I just need to extract the text content, ideally with basic formatting, for further processing.)

Comment: The formatting part is the main issue. To grab just the text `docx` or preferably `docripper` can perform those tasks for you.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky - docx is doing the job nicely now for me, but I'll check out docripper too.

Answer (score 0):

`bootsnap` may have a role to play in all of this since it messes with the startup of Rails. Try making sure all spring processes are cleaned up `ps -ef | grep spring`. Remove `bootsnap` gem and `bundle install`. Then try to start the server again `rails s`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @ddubs. I think I've sorted it without removing bootsnap (see separate answer) but I'll certainly bear the advice in mind for future issues!